# Add rows in Pandas based on condition (grouping)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've googled quite some bit regarding this and could not find an answer that applied to my problem. The issue Im having is that I've got a dataframe and each row has a variable and I want to continuously insert rows with variable C which is the value of variable A + B. Example:

```
      TOWN        YEAR           Var     Value                 
      Amsterdam   2019            A        1
      Amsterdam   2019            B        2
      Amsterdam   2020            A        1
      Amsterdam   2020            B        3
      Rotterdam   2019            A        4
      Rotterdam   2019            B        4
      Rotterdam   2020            A        5
      Rotterdam   2020            B        2
```

Where the desired output would insert a row and sum A and B respectively for rows that are identical in the other columns. My attempt right now backfired as I used groupby and sum, then converted it into a list and then just tried to append it as a seperate column (var_C). The reason it backfired is because I had to duplicate each value to match the length of the original dataset. In the end the length of the list did not match the length of the original dataset.

```
data_current = data[data['var'].isin(['A', 'B'])]
data_var_c = data_current.groupby(['TOWN', 'year'])['value'].sum()
values = data_var_c.tolist()
values_dup = [val for val in values for _ in (0, 1)]
len(values_dup)
```

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pivot stack option:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TOWN': {0: 'Amsterdam', 1: 'Amsterdam', 2: 'Amsterdam', 3: 'Amsterdam',
             4: 'Rotterdam', 5: 'Rotterdam', 6: 'Rotterdam', 7: 'Rotterdam'},
    'YEAR': {0: 2019, 1: 2019, 2: 2020, 3: 2020, 4: 2019, 5: 2019, 6: 2020,
             7: 2020},
    'Var': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'A', 7: 'B'},
    'Value': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 5, 7: 2}
})

new_df = df.pivot(index=['TOWN', 'YEAR'], columns='Var')['Value'] \
    .assign(C=lambda x: x.agg('sum', axis=1)) \
    .stack() \
    .rename('Value') \
    .reset_index()

print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
         TOWN  YEAR Var  Value
0   Amsterdam  2019   A      1
1   Amsterdam  2019   B      2
2   Amsterdam  2019   C      3
3   Amsterdam  2020   A      1
4   Amsterdam  2020   B      3
5   Amsterdam  2020   C      4
6   Rotterdam  2019   A      4
7   Rotterdam  2019   B      4
8   Rotterdam  2019   C      8
9   Rotterdam  2020   A      5
10  Rotterdam  2020   B      2
11  Rotterdam  2020   C      7
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `groupby` and `pd.concat`:

```
result = (
    pd.concat([
        df,
        df.groupby(['TOWN', 'YEAR'], as_index=False)
        .agg(sum)
        .assign(Var = 'C')
        ])
    )

result = result.sort_values(['TOWN', 'YEAR', 'Var'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
       TOWN  YEAR Var  Value
0  Amsterdam  2019   A      1
1  Amsterdam  2019   B      2
0  Amsterdam  2019   C      3
2  Amsterdam  2020   A      1
3  Amsterdam  2020   B      3
1  Amsterdam  2020   C      4
4  Rotterdam  2019   A      4
5  Rotterdam  2019   B      4
2  Rotterdam  2019   C      8
6  Rotterdam  2020   A      5
7  Rotterdam  2020   B      2
3  Rotterdam  2020   C      7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ill mark this as the appropiate answer (since you gave the preferred output as well). The answer I posted only adds it as a column. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I overcomplicated it, it is as simple as grouping by `TOWN` and `Year`, taking the `value` column and apply a `sum` function to get the overall sum:

```
data['c'] = data_current.groupby(['TOWN', 'year'])['value'].transform('sum')
```

This, however, is not the desired output as it adds the summation as another column. Whereas, Nk03's answer adds the summation as a seperate row.